# draw dynamically listboxes

Tags: c#

i want to draw listbox dynamically, either 1 or 1000 on the form in C#. What should I do?
i am taking data from sql server and filling in the listboxes.

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            dt = new DataTable();
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='"+listBox1.SelectedItem+"'", myCon);
            da.Fill(dt);
            int x = dt.Rows.Count;
            listBox2.Items.Clear();
            listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            for (int i = 0; i < x;i++ )
                listBox2.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][0]));
            myCon.Close();
```

with the help of this code i statically draw the list box ,but i want to draw them dynamically

Comment: What client type are you using? What is supposed to be dynamic, the number of listboxes or the content of the listbox? Did you look at data binding?

Answer (score 0):

**Code:** To add **Listitem** dynamically

*Default.apsx*

```
  <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

*Code Behind:*

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string id = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
    string value = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();

    ListItem li=new ListItem();
    li.Text = id;
    li.Value = value;
    ListBox1.Items.Add(li);

}
```

**Code**: To Add **ListBox control** dynamically

```
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
```

*Code Behind:*

```
 for (int i = 0; i < numberOfListBox ; i++)
        {
            ListBox listb = new ListBox();
            ListItem lItem = new ListItem();
            lItem.Value = i.ToString();
            lItem.Text = "item no" + i;
            listb.Items.Add(lItem);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(listb);

        }
```